# Edit Entity with multiple Addresses in the same Symfony2 twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, twig

I have an Entity which represents an Instituion. As so, This Institution has multiple addresses (Adress Entity) each one with Street, Postal code, etc.

The thing is: I have a twig which shows everything about the institution, including a table of addresses where the institution is placed.

All i wanted was to click in one address in the table and have a popup window to edit the address (And then Save button would pass the id of the address to a controller function).

What is the best way to do this? The problem here is that i do not have the id of the address until someone clicks on hit. And then i have to fill the form with the correct information.

Here is what i have:

The table of adresses (in the twig):

```
<tbody>
    {% for local in locais %}
        <tr class="odd gradeX"> 
            <td>{{ local.name}}</td>
        <td>{{ local.address}}</td>
            <td>{{ local.postalCode}}</td>
            <td><a title="Editar" class="label label-info" 
                         onclick="editLocal('{{ local.name}}',  
                                     '{{ local.address}}',
                                     '{{ local.postalCode }}'
                                     '{{ local.id }}');">
                         <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Then I have the following javascript function that fills the edit local form:

```
function editLocal(name, address, postalCode, id){

oFormObject = document.forms['editLocal']; 
oFormObject.elements['fccn_corebundle_localtype_id'].value = id;
oFormObject.elements['fccn_corebundle_localtype_name'].value = name;
oFormObject.elements['fccn_corebundle_localtype_address'].value = address;
oFormObject.elements['fccn_corebundle_localtype_postalCode'].value = codigoPostal;

$('#editLocal').modal('show');
};
```

Everything works ok here!
The form pops up with the correct information!

Then all i wanted was to get the id and pass it to the controller with the edited information so i can persist the existent local entity!

I have the following!

```
<form id="editLocal" class="form-horizontal" 
    action= "{{ path('FccnEduroamEntidadeBundle_editLocal', 
                 { 'idLocal': editLocalForm.vars.value.id }) }}" 
    method="post" {{ form_enctype(editLocalForm) }}>

        {{ form_row(editLocalForm.name) }}
        {{ form_row(editLocalForm.address) }}
        {{ form_row(editLocalForm.postalCode) }}
            {{ form_rest(editLocalForm) }}

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Guardar</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

The problem here is that **editLocalForm.vars.value.id** returns absolutly nothing!
But when i check this tag on chrome i have:
    `<input type="hidden" id="fccn_corebundle_localtype_id" name="fccn_corebundle_localtype[id]" value="1">`

Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Afonso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i get you right, but i would say:

Why do you want the id in the route for your controller?

You could get the id via POST and pass it to persist.
As far as i understand the id is set in the form via javascript to the input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="fccn_corebundle_localtype_id" name="fccn_corebundle_localtype[id]" value="1">
```

So it should be there in your request and you actually dont need it in the route.

Comment: You understood right and got a working answer! Sometimes you are so obsessed with an idea that you get stuck. It worked just fine. All i had to do was 
`$postData  = $request->request->get('fccn_corebundle_localtype');
     $idLocal = $postData['id'];`

Thank you very much!